# Confusion related to derivative of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

What is the derivative of

$\frac{d}{d \theta} \theta^T$

I am a bit confused what it will be. Is it $[ 1 1 1 1]^T$ if $\theta$ is a vector with four elements

Comment: What is the context in which you encountered this notation?

Answer (score 0):

If $\theta$ is an $n$-vector, it has $n$ *partial derivatives*: $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_i}$ for $i=1,...,n$.

Lets look at your example for $n=4$:

$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_1} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_2} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_3} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_4} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

We can summarize this as: $\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\theta := (\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_1} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_2} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_3} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \theta_4}) = I_{4\times 4}$ (4 times 4 identity matrix).

Note: The constant vector $\theta$ can be seen as a very simple vector-valued function $f:R^n \rightarrow R^n$, $f(\theta)=\theta$, so it's derivative is a $n\times n$ (Jacobian) matrix.

Comment: This seems like a plausible interpretation, but is this a standard notation for that?

Comment: Well wikipedia says the Jacobian is written as $\frac{\partial (F_1, ..., F_m)}{\partial (x_1,...,x_n)}$ and this is just the special case for the constant function with $F=\theta$ and $x=\theta$. To be very precise, we probably have to transpose one of the two $\theta$'s...